# Entity look at for cameras and objects

Tags: math, opengl, matrix

I'm currently extending my 3D-engine for a better entity system which includes cameras. This allows me to put cameras into parent entities which may also be in another entity ( and so on... ).

> --Entity
>   ----Entity
>   ------Camera

Now i want to set the cameras look direction, i'm doing this with the following method which is also used to set the look at of a entity:

```
public void LookAt(Vector3 target, Vector3 up)
{
    Matrix4x4 oldValue = _Matrix;
    _Matrix = Matrix4x4.LookAt(_Position, target, up) * Matrix4x4.Scale(_Scale);
    Vector3 p, s;
    Quaternion r;
    Quaternion oldRotation = _Rotation;
    _Matrix.Decompose(out p, out s, out r);
    _Rotation = r;

    // Update dependency properties
    ForceUpdate(RotationDeclaration, _Rotation, oldRotation);
    ForceUpdate(MatrixDeclaration, _Matrix, oldValue);
}
```

But the code is only working for cameras and not for other entities, when using this method for other entities the object is rotating at it's position ( The entity is at a root node, so it has no parent ). The matrix's look at method looks like this:

```
public static Matrix4x4 LookAt(Vector3 position, Vector3 target, Vector3 up)
{
    // Calculate and normalize forward vector
    Vector3 forward = position - target;
    forward.Normalize();
    // Calculate and normalie side vector ( side = forward x up )
    Vector3 side = Vector3.Cross(up, forward);
    side.Normalize();
    // Recompute up as: up = side x forward
    up = Vector3.Cross(forward, side);
    up.Normalize();

    //------------------
    Matrix4x4 result = new Matrix4x4(false)
    {
        M11 = side.X,
        M21 = side.Y,
        M31 = side.Z,
        M41 = 0,

        M12 = up.X,
        M22 = up.Y,
        M32 = up.Z,
        M42 = 0,

        M13 = forward.X,
        M23 = forward.Y,
        M33 = forward.Z,
        M43 = 0,

        M14 = 0,
        M24 = 0,
        M34 = 0,
        M44 = 1

    };

    result.Multiply(Matrix4x4.Translation(-position.X, -position.Y, -position.Z));
    return result;
}
```

The decompose method also returns the wrong value for the position variable `p`. So why is the camera working and the entity not?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago.The problem is that camera transformations are different from others as those are negated.What I did was first to transform camera eye, center and up into world space (transforming those vectors by  its parent model matrix )and then  calculating the lookAt() .That is how it worked for me.

Comment: Hmm so how to generalize it for both the camera and the entities? Actually entities are not working but the camera is?

Comment: Create some virtual method on Entity class which would calculate the matrices.Then , implement it differently for camera entity and for others.That is it.

Comment: Hmm but the camera actually is not a subclass of the entity ( I'm using a component based system, so the camera must use the existing matrice for calculating the correct look at.

Comment: That means you have a wrong understanding about component based system.In such a system all the entities which can be potentially added one to another as parent/child must inherit from some common super class.This way you have perfect polymorphism to deal with scene graph tree members.

Comment: The best example for component based design is Unity3D.Every component there inherits from GameObject .So you can nest objects as containers inside each other and call their  properties using unified interface.